# How can I create a filter area in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLybi.png)

I want to create a filter area in A1 and A2 cells so that when I put drivers' name on these cells, the table (A:C) should be filtered according to the value entered in A1 and A2. Can someone explain me how to write Apps Script to perform such function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How should the table look if cell A1 contains 'Alan' and cell A2 contains 'Helen'?

Comment: In that case, it would be multi-filter. Filtering with 2 driver names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, with both names in C1 and C2 (pls, change sheet name as necessary)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var col = 3
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if (sh.getName() != "Sheet1") return;
  if (e.range.columnStart > col || e.range.columnEnd < col) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2) return;
  var names = sh.getRange(1, col, 2, 1).getValues().flat()
  var range = sh.getRange(3, col, sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn() - col + 1);
  var filter = sh.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) filter.remove();
  if (countNotOccurrences(names, '') == 0) return;
  var hiddenNames = range.getValues().slice(1).map(row => row[0]).filter(who => names.indexOf(who) == -1);
  range.createFilter();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues([...new Set(hiddenNames)]).build();
  sh.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(col, criteria);
}
const countNotOccurrences = (arr, val) => arr.reduce((a, v) => (v !== val ? a + 1 : a), 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you please explain these 2 lines of script?:
if (e.range.columnStart > 1) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2) return;

Comment: And how would this script change if my data has moved to the right side like in this pic?
https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screen-Shot-2022-02-21-at-19.38.37.png

Comment: when you change value or copy a range, google sheet fetch a json `e` that has some attributes as : `e.range.columnEnd e.range.columnStart e.range.rowEnd e.range.rowStart` to determine the area. So I check if this area affects A1:A2 by checking rowStart (has to be <=2) and columnStar (has to be =1) and I reject if not

Comment: Thank you, Mike! But I am still getting error when I moved my data to the right side like in this pic: linkpicture.com/q/Screen-Shot-2022-02-21-at-19.38.37.png

Can you please help me what should I change to reflect changes in the script?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this probably:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart > 1) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2) return;
  filter_table(e.value);
}

function filter_table(name) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3);
  var data = range.getValues(); 
  var hidden_values = data.map(x => x[0]).filter(x => x != name);

  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) filter.remove();

  range.createFilter();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(hidden_values).build();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);
}
```

It filteres the range A3:C every time you edit cell A1 or cell A2.

But I'm not sure though what do you want to get when the two cells contain different names.

**Update**

Here is the 'multi-filter' solution :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart > 1) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2) return;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() != 'Filter') return; // <-- to limit the trigger only one sheet 'Filter'

  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3);
  var [name1, name2, ...data] = range.getValues();
  var hidden_values = data.map(x => x[0])
    .filter(x => x != name1[0] && x != name2[0]);

  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) filter.remove();
  range.offset(2,0).createFilter();
  if (name1[0] + name2[0] == '') return; 

  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(hidden_values).build();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);
}
```

If both of the cells are empty you will see all the rows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try it now. If 2 cells contain 2 different names, it should show data related to those 2 driver names. So it would be multi-filter. Just like this in below picture:
https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screen-Shot-2022-02-20-at-23.32.32.png

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working. While I integrate it to bigger file I have (it has several sheets), should I specify the sheet name?

Comment: And what would be the script for the dates, not names?

Comment: I wanted to specify the exact sheet where script should work because currently it is being applied to each sheet I have. Can you pls correct me?

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart > 1) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2) return;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName('Filter');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3);
  var [name1, name2, ...data] = range.getValues();
  var hidden_values = data.map(x => x[0])

Comment: To limit the script just one sheet ('Filter' I suppose) you need to add one line in the code. I've updated the second script, see the new commented line. As for the dates, probably it's need to to change `range.getValues()` to `range.getDisplayValues()`. Dates is a tricky thing, actual implementation depends on how your sheet looks like.

Answer (score 0):

#### Driver Data

```
function MyFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  osh.clearContents();
  const sr = 3;
  const dA = sh.getRange(1,1,2).getValues().flat();
  const name = dA[0] + ' ' + dA[1];
  const nameColumn = 1;
  const vo = sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[nameColumn -1] == name);
  osh.getRange(1,1,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you explain me why we are dealing with 2 sheets? Does it get values from the first one and move it by filtering into second one?

Comment: I'm just using osh for the filtered output